# Can anyone explain the meaning of this statement " var upload_file_count_text = +filenames.length + +upFiles;"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across a piece of code written in below format in a .js file. I am wondering what would it actually do. Just trying to understanding the purpose of this statement.

```
var upload_file_count_text = +filenames.length + +upFiles;
```

Comment: Looks like quotes have been stripped out of the snippet - please try formatting it as code, if so. Apart from that, it simply looks like a smelly way to build a string from the given variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` prefix on the variable names is the 'unary' operator. In JavaScript it is in effect shorthand for `Number()`. The code is changing both `filenames.length` and `upFiles` to ints from string so their values can be added instead of concatenated.

The code is equivalent to:

```
var upload_file_count_text = Number(filenames.length) + Number(upFiles);
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript prefix **+** is use to convert string to Int

```
var upload_file_count_text = +filenames.length + +upFiles;
```

Above code first **+filenames.length** which  simply convert it into **int type**